# Concurrent Database Connections

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, corruption, connection

How do SQL databases prevent corruption from occurring when two or three connections to it modify the same table at the same time (or even the same row)?

I was thinking of an theoretical possibility that could occur on databases which have multiple server based load balanced front ends:

- Server 1 accesses the central database
- Server 2 accesses the central database
- Server 1 gets info for user X in central database
- Server 2 gets info for same user X in central database
- Server 1 sets new data for user X in central database after doing some work (could be a do or do not transaction)
- Server 2 sets new data for user X in central database

Which at this point user X would contain invalid entries as it has basically overwritten the work Server 1 just did to that same user.

I was thinking about constantly checking the same table & row to see if it has been modified lately but still nothing is stopping that same table & row being modified by something else between the time it has checked and the time it will write to the DB after checking.

I'm just trying to get an idea how large databases with millions of users work and how they are distributed over tens or hundreds of separate servers.

Comment: Searching on _database transactional integrity_ may help answer your question.

Comment: Yep, I was trying to search information related to this late last night, already found many good links this morning such as https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx.

Comment: I'm glad that you found what you needed to satisfy your curiosity, and that you answered your own question.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Database transactional integrity was what I was looking for.

Good links to read:

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_Levels.2C_Read_Phenomena_and_Locks

Thanks